# Select all orders by one customer

Tags: sql

I have three tables, `orders`, `orders_details` and `customers`. I need to select orders by one customer for the `orders` table so I did this

`orders` columns:

```
id
customer_id
created
vat
discount
amount
paid
```

`orders_details` columns:

```
id
order_id
cost
qty
product
```

The SQL I used

```
SELECT 
    orders.*, 
    SUM(orders_details.qty*orders_details.cost) as amount, 
    SUM(orders_details.qty) AS qty 
FROM 
    orders, 
    orders_details, 
    customers 
WHERE 
    orders.customer_id = customers.id 
    AND orders_details.order_id = orders.id 
    AND orders.customer_id = 1
```

but I am getting a wrong qty of 30 instead of 20 and the amount is wrong

Comment: i think you should use GROUP BY on orders.id

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `GROUP BY` clause which I'm guessing should be on `orders.id`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to aggregate per order you need a `GROUP BY` clause. Also you [should use proper JOIN syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), and might consider using aliases to make the query more compact.

```
SELECT 
    o.*, 
    SUM(od.qty * od.cost) AS amount, 
    SUM(od.qty) AS qty 
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN orders_details od ON od.order_id = o.id
INNER JOIN customers c ON o.customer_id = c.id     -- not used, might be excluded
WHERE o.customer_id =1
GROUP BY o.id
```

Depending on what database system you are using you might need to include all columns referenced in o.* in the `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY o.id, o.customer_id, o.created, o.vat, o.discount, o.amount, o.paid
```

Last note: as you don't seem to use any data from the customers table you probably could exclude that table altogether.